# If the upper Darboux integral of a non-negative bounded function $f$ equals zero then $f$ is integrable

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I got this question:

Let $f$ be a non-negative, bounded function on the interval $[0,1]$ such that it's upper Darboux integral equals 0, i.e. $\int_0^{1^-} f(x)\;dx = 0$.
Prove or disprove by a counterexample that $f$ is integrable in $[0,1]$.

I tried to show that the lower Darboux integral of $f $ also equals 0, i.e. $\int_{0_{\_}}^1 f(x)\;dx = 0$ and so $f$ will be integrable on $[0,1]$ But failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the lower integral is the sum of a bunch of terms, each of which is the width of an interval times the inf on that interval. Since f is nonnegative, the inf is at least 0, so the lower sum is greater than or equal to zero.

You *also* know that each lower sum is less than each upper sum.

Now can you work out the last bits?

Comment: Yes thanks. I proved the statement.